# Create pyramid from 3in TIFFs

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-pyramids

I have a couple of terabytes of 3in GeoTIFFs that I would like to host on my GeoServer (used by a non profit during disasters when there is no Internet). I have read that the best way to host these images is my creating mosaic overviews so that the client is not trying to load terabyes of data at a time. I have looked at gdal_retile but that appears to be doing the opposite of what i am trying to do. I have the most zoomed in image and want to create the mosaics for overviews.

I am using GeoServer and QGIS as my client.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll need to stitch your images together into a full size high resolution image and then chop it up into pieces.

The first step can be done using either `gdal_merge` or a VRT. Then you'll be looking to make an [image pyramid](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) which does use `gdal_retile` to do this.

I have a [tutorial](https://www.ianturton.com/tutorials/bluemarble.html) that describes the process with some bash scripts to help though for a smaller image.